# Angular-UI (bootstrap) popover not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

So I'm working on getting a popover to show up on a button using Angular-UI. I tested out tooltips first and they're working perfectly...but when I use popovers it's not working at all.

My controller is empty, just has $scope. Here's my code for the button (taken directly from the demo on their website):

```
<button popover-placement="bottom" popover="On the Bottom!" class="btn btn-default">Bottom</button>
```

What I'm confused about is that if the tooltip directive is working, why isn't the popover? Am I missing something from my controller?

Here's my controller even though I don't think it will be of much help:

```
angular.module('module').controller('MyController', ['$scope',
function($scope) {

}
]);
```

Hope I can get this solved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the default popover-trigger is click? but yes it makes no sense if angular boostrap tooltips are working already, maybe you have some broken HTML tags

Comment: @sjm thanks...I thought I was going crazy haha. Maybe someone else has dealt with this before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check 2 things:

The first is to make sure the ui.bootstrap dependency is injected

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

The second is to make sure you have all the bootstrap stylesheets added as bootstrap ui uses these

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on a bigger project with this so I have ui.bootstrap included globally....and I think I have all the css files. What could be wrong? :(

Comment: I would just double check to make sure the templates for the popover are there, if you are using bootstrap sass or less, it's possible you don't have the popover templates.  There is a file called something like bootstrap-tpls that also needs to be included in your css.  That's my best guess.  Good luck.